# JSON An error occurred during the compilation of the requested file, or one of its dependencies. ; expected

Tags: c#, json, sharepoint, formatting

I'm trying to format this JSON to be able to assign it to DataProviderJSON properly.
It keeps giving me an error on variable 'testing':

**An error occurred during the compilation of the requested file, or one of its dependencies. ; expected**

```
 using (ContentBySearchWebPart box = GetControlByIDPath(ControlID, this.Page.Controls[0]) as ContentBySearchWebPart)
    {
                    string testing;
                    testing = "{\"QueryGroupName\":\"Default\",\"QueryPropertiesTemplateUrl\":"",\"IgnoreQueryPropertiesTemplateUrl\":false,\"SourceID\":\"8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89\",\"SourceName\":\"Local SharePoint Results\",\"SourceLevel\":\"Ssa\",\"CollapseSpecification\":"",\"QueryTemplate\":\"#test (ContentTypeId:0x01FD4FB0210AB50249908EAA47E6BD3CFE8B* OR ContentTypeId:0x01FD59A0DF25F1E14AB882D2C87D4874CF84* OR ContentTypeId:0x012002* OR ContentTypeId:0x0107* OR WebTemplate=COMMUNITY)\",\"FallbackSort\":[],\"FallbackSortJson\":[],\"RankRules\":[],\"RankRulesJson\":\"[]\",\"AsynchronousResultRetrieval\":false,\"SendContentBeforeQuery\":true,\"BatchClientQuery\":true,\"FallbackLanguage\":-1,\"FallbackRankingModelID\":\"\",\"EnableStemming\":true,\"EnablePhonetic\":false,\"EnableNicknames\":false,\"EnableInterleaving\":false,\"EnableQueryRules\":true,\"EnableOrderingHitHighlightedProperty\":false,\"HitHighlightedMultivaluePropertyLimit\":-1,\"IgnoreContextualScope\":true,\"ScopeResultsToCurrentSite\":false,\"TrimDuplicates\":false,\"Properties\":{\"TryCache\":true,\"Scope\":\"{Site.URL}\",\"UpdateLinksForCatalogItems\":true,\"EnableStacking\":true,\"ListId\":\"8837b1d4-c29a-4ab0-9385-f483c19b25ec\",\"ListItemId\":4},\"PropertiesJson\":\"{\"TryCache\":true,\"Scope\":\"{Site.URL}\",\"UpdateLinksForCatalogItems\":true,\"EnableStacking\":true,\"ListId\":\"8837b1d4-c29a-4ab0-9385-f483c19b25ec\",\"ListItemId\":4}\",\"ClientType\":\"ContentSearchRegular\",\"UpdateAjaxNavigate\":true,\"SummaryLength\":180,\"DesiredSnippetLength\":90,\"PersonalizedQuery\":false,\"FallbackRefinementFilters\":null,\"IgnoreStaleServerQuery\":false,\"RenderTemplateId\":\"DefaultDataProvider\",\"AlternateErrorMessage\":null,\"Title\":""}";
                    box.DataProviderJSON = testing; }
```

UPDATE: Now it seems to be working but i'm getting a new error on

`box.DataProviderJSON = testing;`

**Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentException: Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected.**

This is the JSON:

```
"{\"QueryGroupName\":\"Default\",\"QueryPropertiesTemplateUrl\":\"\",\"IgnoreQueryPropertiesTemplateUrl\":false,\"SourceID\":\"8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89\",\"SourceName\":\"Local SharePoint Results\",\"SourceLevel\":\"Ssa\",\"CollapseSpecification\":\"\",\"QueryTemplate\":\"#test(ContentTypeId:0x01FD4FB0210AB50249908EAA47E6BD3CFE8B* OR ContentTypeId:0x01FD59A0DF25F1E14AB882D2C87D4874CF84* OR ContentTypeId:0x012002* OR ContentTypeId:0x0107* OR WebTemplate=COMMUNITY)  \",\"FallbackSort\":[],\"FallbackSortJson\":[],\"RankRules\":[],\"RankRulesJson\":\"[]\",\"AsynchronousResultRetrieval\":false,\"SendContentBeforeQuery\":true,\"BatchClientQuery\":true,\"FallbackLanguage\":-1,\"FallbackRankingModelID\":\"\",\"EnableStemming\":true,\"EnablePhonetic\":false,\"EnableNicknames\":false,\"EnableInterleaving\":false,\"EnableQueryRules\":true,\"EnableOrderingHitHighlightedProperty\":false,\"HitHighlightedMultivaluePropertyLimit\":-1,\"IgnoreContextualScope\":true,\"ScopeResultsToCurrentSite\":false,\"TrimDuplicates\":false,\"Properties\":{\"TryCache\":true,\"Scope\":\"Site.URL\",\"UpdateLinksForCatalogItems\":true,\"EnableStacking\":true,\"ListId\":\"8837b1d4-c29a-4ab0-9385-f483c19b25ec\",\"ListItemId\":4},\"PropertiesJson\":{\"TryCache\":true,\"Scope\":\"{Site.URL}\",\"UpdateLinksForCatalogItems\":true,\"EnableStacking\":true,\"ListId\":\"8837b1d4-c29a-4ab0-9385-f483c19b25ec\",\"ListItemId\":4},\"ClientType\":\"ContentSearchRegular\",\"UpdateAjaxNavigate\":true,\"SummaryLength\":180,\"DesiredSnippetLength\":90,\"PersonalizedQuery\":false,\"FallbackRefinementFilters\":null,\"IgnoreStaleServerQuery\":false,\"RenderTemplateId\":\"DefaultDataProvider\",\"AlternateErrorMessage\":null,\"Title\":\"\"}";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not escape the `"` after `QueryPropertiesTemplateUrl`. Thus the string is ended there and the compiler is missing the `;` to end the statement.

```
testing = "{\"QueryGroupName\":\"Default\",\"QueryPropertiesTemplateUrl\":" //; The string ends, but is not followed by an semicolon - thus the compile error.
```

You rather want to use

```
testing = "[...]\"QueryPropertiesTemplateUrl\":\"\",\"IgnoreQueryPropertiesTemplateUrl[...]";
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked ;) Now is giving me this error on box.DataProviderJSON = testing: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentException: Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected.

Comment: Check your `PropertiesJson` attribute in `testing`. You want to assign a JSON object as value (like you did for `Properties`), but you put the object in double quotes which is why it's interpreted as string. Thus you assign the string `{` to your PropertiesJson instead of the whole object and the rest of the object can not be parsed due to the wrong syntax. If removing the double quotes does not fix your problem, try removing all attributes from your JSON and check if it throws any errors - afterwards add the attributes in one-by-one to see which one causes the error.

Comment: Hi, i was able to retrieve the JSON via debug and i noticed, using a Jsonvalidator, that it wasn't well formatted. Now the JSON is fine, i have a problem on DataProviderJSON: Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Comment: This is probably caused because you are trying to convert an array from your JSON object (noted by `[]`) in a string variable in your code (possibly instead of an array of strings `string[]` ?)

Comment: Yep, i need to assign that JSON to DataProviderJson property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.webcontrols.resultscriptwebpart.dataproviderjson.aspx , which is a String. How can i do that?

Comment: Using string jsonData = "{\"QueryGroupName\":\"Default\"}"; it works fine, so it's a problem with formatting i guess. The question is: where? I edited the question with the new JSON

Comment: I don't know the types of the properties you are assigning, so i can't give you a concrete answer. However the errormessage is telling you that you are assigning an array to a string. Thus I would suggest you search your JSON string for arrays (search for `[`) and remove all your attributes to which an array is assigned. Then put them back in one-by-one to check which one is causing the problems and assign a string to that one instead of an array. (I assume one of the properties with an empty array `[]` should be an empty string instead.